# making an arithmetic calculator function in python

Tags: python, math

We have to make a simple arithemtic calculator function in python

My code is pretty primitive, but I thought it should work. Why doesn't it?
Why doesnt it return sum?

```
def calculator(a,b,c):
    
    sum = 0
    
    if a == "-":
        sum = b - c
    elif a == "+":
        sum = b + c
    elif a == "*":
        sum = b * c
    elif a == "/":
        sum = b / c
        
    return sum

calculator("-", 5, 3)
```

Comment: if I do print(sum) it does the trick

Comment: Because returning something does not implicitly print it unless you are coding live in "interactive mode" or in IDLE or whatever. You have to explicitly print stuff in order for it to be printed to the screen.

Comment: what is interactive mode @RandomDavis

Comment: Do `print(calculator("-", 5, 3))` at the bottom. You need to tell Python what to do with the result of your function.

Answer (score 2):

The code works. You are just returning the value and not doing anything with it. At least to see it you can change the last line to `print(calculator("-", 5, 3))` to see the result.